# How can this structure can be document with OpenApi 3?

Tags: openapi

I'm trying to document a response object, but the structure is like this:

```
{
  "1": {
       "prop1":1,
       "prop2":2,
       "prop3":3
  },
  "2": {
       "prop1":1,
       "prop2":2,
       "prop3":3
  },
  "3": {
       "prop1":1,
       "prop2":2,
       "prop3":3
  },
  "4": {
       "prop1":1,
       "prop2":2,
       "prop3":3
  }
}
```

How that is correctly documented?

Comment: Are `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` arbitrary property names (as in a map/dictionary), or does each of the nested objects have the same properties?

Comment: Same nested objects...